# FOS and Fr3d ldap Bundle with symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, ldap, fr3dldapbundle

Login for the first time and getting registered in the database. Though now I got the problem that I can't login a second time.

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"
"fr3d/ldap-bundle": "2.0.*@dev"
```

I have seen similar issies, but if "bindRequiresDn: true" i get in my logs:

> [2013-07-10 11:37:18] ldap_driver.DEBUG: ldap_bind(Nikita, ****) [] []
>
> [2013-07-10 11:37:18] ldap_driver.DEBUG: 0x1: Failed to retrieve DN for account: Nikita [Binding requires username in DN form] [] []

and can't login.

But if i change:

> .../vendor/fr3d/ldap-bundle/FR3D/LdapBundle/Driver/ZendLdapDriver.php

```
 if ($user instanceof LdapUserInterface && $user->getDn()) {
     $bind_rdn = $user->getDn();
 } else {
     $bind_rdn = $user->getUsername();
 }
```

on

```
 if ($user instanceof LdapUserInterface) {
    $bind_rdn = $user->getDn();
 } else {
    $bind_rdn = $user->getUsername();
 }
```

all works good.

My config

```
 fr3d_ldap:
    driver:
        host:                     "%ldap_host%"
        port:                     "%ldap_port%"
        username:                 "%ldap_username%"
        password:                 "%ldap_password%"
        baseDn:                     ou=hello, dc=h, dc=i, dc=ru
        bindRequiresDn:        true
        accountFilterFormat: (&(samaccountname=%s))

    user:
        baseDn: ou=hello, dc=h, dc=i, dc=ru
        filter: (&(objectClass=user))
        attributes:
           - { ldap_attr: samaccountname,  user_method: setUsername }
```

Comment: Where is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems when initially using FR3DLdapBundle and after logging out and then trying to login the 2nd time.

You may want to read through my blog article here:
[Symfony AD Integration](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/)

I'm not sure if you already got an answer or got this working, but hopefully this helps someone else out!